# Command line arguments without the hyphen

Tags: c, command-line, arguments

How can I parse arguments without the hyphen in C?

I.e. `virsh install vm`

or

`git pull origin master`

When I tried it out, if there is no `-` prefix, everything just gets ignored and `argc` returns `1` (`argv[0]` is the program call).

I'm using Linux, but it would be nice if there was a cross platform method to achieve this.

UPDATE: the problem was me using a `#` in front of the first argument, I was trying to pass in #XX eg number_program #12. Needless to say this doesn't work.

Comment: It is very unclear what it is you are asking.  ***[READ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)*** this for help on asking a good question.

Comment: Um, your `argc` and `argv` will reflect whatever is on the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using some library to parse the arguments for you? There is no special 'hyphen' arguments when passing in parameters to a C program specifically. Parse argv however you like.

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        int i;
        for(i=0; i<argc; i++) {
                //dont do this without proper input validation
                printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Example run:

```
$ ./a.out test test test -hyphen
./a.out
test
test
test
-hyphen
```

Answer (score 1):

`argv` contains the program name and the arguments to the program, in the order they were given in the command line.<sup>*</sup>  Hyphens aren't special; they just make it easy for both people and computers to separate options from other args.

If you want to interpret args a certain way, that's your prerogative.  That's what `git` does, basically interpreting `argv[1]` (if it exists, of course) as the name of a subcommand.  And you don't need any libraries in order to do that.  You just need to decide how you want the args interpreted.

<sup><sup>*</sup> Modulo some cross-platform differences in how args are parsed; *nix typically does some pre-parsing for you and expands wildcard patterns, for example.  You won't have 100% cross-platform compatibility unless you understand those differences and are ready for them.</sup>